# a tester which does not know the names of files

Tags: c, shell

There are some test cases for a program in format: `??.in` ans `??.out` in directories 
`./input` and `./output` such that for each test the first part of the names are equal e.g. `test1.in`, `test1.out`

How can I write a code which sweeps through these files together? (may be the files can be looked for in alphabetical order [in each directory]...)

Answer (score 1):

Get list of all files in a directory using [opendir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) (and related functions), and then parse the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    char in_filename[100];
    char out_filename[100];

    sprintf(in_filename, "./input/test%d.in", i);
    sprintf(out_filename, "./output/test%d.out", i);
    /* use in_filename and out_filename as you see fit */
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: a test name can be `test3a.in`

Comment: use `"%x"` for hexadecimal output :-)

Comment: what to do for : `test1.in`, `test2.in`, `test3a.in`, ... + how can these run in shell?